# Bottom sheet inside the tooltip not working , This popup is showing behind the bottom sheet

Tags: android, popup, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet I am loading the popup but it does not showing on the bottomsheet. This popup is showing behind the bottom sheet

```
    CustomTextView textView = (CustomTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.info_disc);
    textView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    popup.setWidth((int) (width - (view.getX() + view.getWidth() + ViewUtils.convertDpToPixel(12, context))));
    popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    Rect p = locateView(view);
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, p.right, p.top + 15);
```

Comment: Is your bottom sheet a `BottomSheetDialog` or `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: That would be why, since that's a completely separate window from the `Activity`. Is the `view` its showing next to in the `Activity` or the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? In either case, that's what you should be passing to `showAtLocation()`, instead of `layout`.

Comment: I have activity in that loading the bottom sheet ,
Inside the bottom sheet showing the popup window, When i call popup window it showing behind the bottomsheet

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, you just need to pass `popup.showAtLocation()` a `View` that is attached to the `BottomSheetDialog`'s window, not `layout`, since that's what you presumably just inflated above. If `view` in that `locateView(view)` call is indeed in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, then pass it that instead: `popup.showAtLocation(view, ...`.

Comment: I passed the view from the bottom sheet dialog, How to open the popup in the bottom sheet dialog, is there any snippet

Comment: There's really nothing more to it than what we've already discussed. You have to pass `showAtLocation()` a `View` that is currently attached to the `BottomSheetDialog`, because that's how the `PopupWindow` figures out which window to show for, and above. Your snippet shows that you're passing `layout`, but that is not attached to the `BottomSheetDialog`, because that's what you just inflated for the `PopupWindow`'s content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211934/discussion-between-ramesh-sambu-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the bottom sheet is a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, and the `BottomSheetDialog` it controls is indeed a `Dialog`; a completely separate window from the `Activity`'s window. The `PopupWindow` is associating with the wrong window, which is why it shows behind the `BottomSheetDialog`.

The `View` passed to `PopupWindow`'s `show*()` methods is used to determine which window to associate the `PopupWindow` with. In the given snippet:

```
popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, p.right, p.top + 15);
```

`layout` is the `View` inflated to act as the `PopupWindow`'s content, and is therefore not attached to any window yet, so it does not know to show above the `BottomSheetDialog`.

The fix is to simply pass `showAtLocation()` a `View`, any `View`, that is currently attached to the `BottomSheetDialog` when the call is made:

```
popup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, p.right, p.top + 15);
```