# popupwindow is showing behind bottomsheetfragment instead it should be above bottomsheetfragment.Here is my code of bottomsheetfragment

Tags: android, kotlin

code inside bottomsheetfragment.
the popupwindow is showing behing bottomsheetfragment.

```
  val window = PopupWindow(requireContext())
  val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer__feedback, null)
  window.contentView = view
  window.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
  window.setFocusable(true)
  window.setOutsideTouchable(false)

  val sendFeedback = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_sendFeedback)
  val feedbackMessage  = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.feedback_message)

  sendFeedback.setOnClickListener {

      if(feedbackMessage.text.toString().exIsNotEmptyOrNullOrBlank()){
          window.dismiss()
          presenter.callNetwork(ConstantsApi.CALL_FEEDBACK, dmiConnector = FeedbackApiCall())}
      else {
         showToast(activity,"Please fill feedback")
      }


  }
  window.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)

  [enter image description here][1]
```

here is my code of popupwindow inside bottomsheetfragment.

Comment: The `View` in the `showAtLocation()` call needs to be one inside the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, not the popup's `View`. Change the `window.showAtLocation(view, ...)` call to `window.showAtLocation(sendFeedback, ...)`, for example. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61288070.

Comment: I changed   window.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0) to window.showAtLocation(sendFeedback, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0) but it doesnt work

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's my bad. I didn't notice that you're finding `sendFeedback` inside the popup's `View`. Pick some other `View`, then. You can use any `View` directly inside the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` – e.g., whichever `View` is showing the popup – or even just the `Fragment`'s whole `View`, `this.view`.